# Continuous version of binomial expansion

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

Is there a continuous version of the binomial expansion? That is, if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then
$$
(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}b^k.
$$
However, if $x\in\mathbb{R}$, is there anything we can say about
$$
(a+b)^x
$$
regarding its expansion? I'm using the term 'expansion' here in a rather apprehensive way, but can we make sense of it in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binomial power series is defined for any exponent $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ by
$$(1+x)^{\alpha}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-k+1)}{k!}x^k$$
The fraction generalizes binomial coefficients.  If $\alpha$ is a non-negative integer the series is actually finite since eventually $\alpha=k$ for some value of $k$ and gives the usual binomial expansion. Otherwise it is infinite.

As this is a series one needs to worry about convergence. The main results are that the series is always convergent when $|x|<1$, always divergent when $|x|>1$ except when $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ (since the series is finite then). When $|x|= 1$ the behaviour of the series depends more subtly on $\alpha$ (this case is mostly relevant when we allow $x$ to be complex).

A slight modification along the lines of
$$(a+b)^x=a^x\left(1+\dfrac{b}{a}\right)^x$$
lets you handle the more general version that you have in mind.

You can find a derivation on the wiki page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series
or in any text about power series, as the binomial series is a very standard and useful power series.

NB: Both $\alpha$ and $x$ can actually be complex in this discussion without much changes.

Comment: It is a finite series if $\alpha$ is a *non-negative* integer

Comment: Thanks ! Integers are by default non-negative in my native language. I'll correct.

Comment: In mine too, but I've learnt to cater for this point– all the more so that for many students  $0$ is not an element of $\mathbf N$.

Comment: Yes I should pay more attention when I write in English. Same goes with increasing/non-decreasing and positive/non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: the binomial series, under mild hypotheses. Suppose $a, b > 0$ and $a<b$.

By Taylor's formula, as $\frac ab<1$ we have
\begin{align}(a+b)^x&=b^x\Bigl(1+\frac ab\Bigr)^x=b^x\Bigl(1+x\frac ab+\frac{x(x-1)}2\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\dots+\binom{x}{k}\frac{b^k}{k!\,a^k}+\dotsm\Bigr)\\
&=b^x+x\,ab^{x-1}+\binom x2   a^2b^{x-2}+\dots+\binom xk x^kb^{x-k}+\dotsm
\end{align}
where we denomte $\dfrac{x}k$ the *generalised binomial coefficient*:
$$\binom xk=\frac{x(x-1)\dots(x-k+1)}{k!}.$$